# Adminer- Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: adminer

I'm getting this error when i try to access my phpmyadmin databases from my site at 000webhost
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
but when i type localhost in URL and enter my login details through adminer's login, i could access phphmyadmin panel, but when tried using the site,i get the error..Any suggestions
My site is http://salon.host56.com/salonadmin.php

Comment: It may be that adminer is running in a different server than the one giving the error? Then, it's unclear to me if you are giving a password in the first case (it seems no, but in the second case you said you put a password in order to access). The question is a little unclear and may not be related to programming at all

Comment: I mean there is no password in both the cases. I have put adminer's php file in the my wamp server and ran it through browser and I was able to access the databases. I uploaded the adminer's php file to my site I got at 000webhost using ftp. Now when I open my site and click the php file,I get the login portal of adminer. I enter the same credentials and I get "access denied" error.

Comment: then the database in your wamp server and in your 000webhost server have different user permissions. try to re-set them (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is the file permission? if the server is unix-like try `chmod 644 salonadmin.php`

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo mysql_secure_installation` to setup password for root user